# contact form email to text message is not working

Tags: php, android, email, text, contacts

Hello I hope you guys can help me out I have this contact form that is suppose to send an email to technicians email and his phone number.

Now everything is working but he not receiving the text, I feel as though its his phone that is the problem because I used my girlfriend phone number that uses the same carrier and she receives the texts fine and as well as everyone else who's suppose to receive text, but when I send to his phone it just doesn't work...is there something I'm missing ???, **NOTE: HE HAS AN ANDROID BUT EVERYONE ELSE HAS I PHONE. WHEN I COMPOSE AN EMAIL DIRECTLY FROM MY GMAIL AND SEND IT TO HIS PHONE, IT WORKS** the contact form work's with my girlfriends phone, managers, and other colleagues some people who have the same carrier as of the technician worked as well but just not for him (the technician) ...It boggles my mind please somebody HELP!

```html
<?php

$email='1231231234@tmomail.net, 1231231234@tmomail.net,myemail@gmail.com';

$email1=$_POST['Email1'];
$email2=$_POST['Email2'];
$from2=$_POST['Email1'];
$from=$_POST['Email1'];
$subject="Maintenance Request";
//^this is the subject of the email that serivce gets. 
$problem=$_POST['Box'];
$select=$_POST['Select'];
$name=$_POST['Name'];
$phone=$_POST['Phone'];
$number=$_POST['Number'];
$mlocation=$_POST['Machinelocation'];
$orgname=$_POST['OrganisationName'];
//^these information pulls what the customer answers in the field

$message="Name: ".$name."\r\n"."Organization: ".$orgname."\r\n"."Email: ".$from."\r\n"."Phone: ".$phone ."\r\n"."Machine: ".$select."\r\n"."Machine Location: ".$mlocation."\r\n"."Problem: ".$problem ;

$confirmation_subject = 'Your recent Maintenance request';
//^this is the subject of the confirmation email
$confirmation_sender = 'COMPANY NAME HERE<info@youremail.com>';
$msg = "".$name."\r\n" ."Thank you for your recent Maintenance request. A member of our team will respond to your request as soon as possible."."\r\nBelow you will see a copy of your request"."\r\n\n"."Name: ".$name."\r\n"."organization: ".$orgname."\r\n"."Email: ".$from."\r\n"."Phone: ".$phone ."\r\n"."Machine: ".$select."\r\n"."Machine Location: ".$mlocation."\r\n"."Problem: ".$problem ;
//^this is confirmation message message" 

if ($number !=10) {
    die("You are not a human! or your answer was incorrect!, Please go back and try again.");
}
else {
mail ($email1, $confirmation_subject,$msg, 'From: ' .$confirmation_sender );
}

if(!filter_var($email1, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    die("Invalid email ($email1)");
}
if ($email1 == $email2) {
    mail ($email, $subject, $message, "from:".$from);
    header("location: siteethankyou.php");
}
else {
    echo "This ($email2) email address is different from ($email1).\n";
}

?>
```

```html
<div name="my-form" >
<div class="container">  
  <form id="contact" action="EmailHandler.php" method="post">
    <h3>Repair Form</h3>
    <h4>Contact us today, and get reply with in 24 hours!</h4>
    <fieldset>
      <input name="Name" type="text" autofocus required id="Name" placeholder="Your name" tabindex="1">
    </fieldset>
     <fieldset>
      <input name="OrganisationName" type="text" autofocus required id="OrganisationName" placeholder=" Your Organisation Name" tabindex="1">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <p>
        <input name="Email1" type="email" autofocus required id="Email1" placeholder="Your Email Address" tabindex="2">
      </p>
      <p class="underfield"><em style="font-size: 10px">please provide your email address to better assist you.</em></p>
    </fieldset>
     <fieldset>
      <input name="Email2" type="email" autofocus required id="Email2" placeholder=" Verify Your Email Address" tabindex="2">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input name="Phone" type="tel" autofocus required id="Phone" placeholder="Your Phone Number" tabindex="3" maxlength="12">
    </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <select name="Select" autofocus required class="container" id="Select" onchange="changeSelectValue();">
            <option selected="selected">Select</option>
            <option value="Carpet Machine">Carpet Machine</option>
            <option value="Coffee Brewer">Coffee Brewer</option>
            <option value="Floor Machine">Floor Machine</option>
            <option value="Rider Scrubber Commercial">Rider Scrubber Commercial </option>
            <option value="Rider Scrubber Industrial">Rider Scrubber Industrial</option>
            <option value="Sweeper Commercial">Sweeper Commercial</option>
            <option value="Sweeper Industrial">Sweeper Industrial</option>
            <option value="Vacuum Cleaner">Vacuum Cleaner</option>
            <option value="Water Cooler">Water Cooler</option>
            <option value="Wet / Dry">Wet / Dry</option>
            <option value="Test">Test</option>
            <!--the value has to match the php-->
      </select>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset>
      <input name="Machinelocation" type="text" autofocus required id="Machinelocation" placeholder="Your Machine Location Address" tabindex="2">
       </fieldset>
      <p class="underfield2"> please provide the address location of the machine. city,state,zipe code</p>
    <fieldset>
      <p>
        <textarea name="Box" autofocus required id="Box" placeholder="What's wrong with your machine...?" tabindex="5"></textarea>
      </p>
    </fieldset>
    
             <fieldset>
      <input name="Number" type="text" autofocus required class="container" id="Question" placeholder="What does 5 + 5 = ?" tabindex="1">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <p>&nbsp;        </p>
      <p>
      <input name="submit" type="submit" autofocus class="container4" id="submit" value="Send Request"></p></fieldset>

  </form>
 
  
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where are you sending a text message? The `mail()` command doesn't do that.

Comment: well its being working so far for everyone else just not this person in particular for some reason by using mail, but if that's not how its done, how should i send the form to a phone as text message? @JeremyHarris

Comment: Do you get any server bounce messages sent back to the From address? It could be an SPF filter (since you are not sending from the usual server for the From address) or a real-time blacklist that is used by the Android email->text-message forwarder that isn't used by the equivalent iPhone system. When you send from a regular email system that is functioning properly you usually won't have those types of problems but server scripts often do.

Comment: well the "from" if im correct is using the email the customer inputs into the field to send the message, so sense i've been testing the form using my person email to see if im receiving the confirmation email and using my other email to receive the form im not receiving any bounce back on either emails. @manassehkatz

Comment: how would know if its the blacklist thing? @manassehkatz

Comment: @twinaholic I personally use the Twilio SMS API (not free, but cheap) to send text messages. There are other services out there.

Comment: thats says sms would it work for mms? @JeremyHarris

Comment: Yes. I believe so.

Comment: @twinaholic The only ways you can tell why a message isn't getting through is if the recipient tells you because they got something (e.g., a special code added to the Subject) or if you get a bounce message. Since you aren't getting either one, it is hard to figure it out. What often works is to use for From: an email account that is hosted on the same server. If the server is a typical shared server with domain/hosting/email then any email from the hosted domain will usually work. If you're using your own server then that often won't work. It gets complicated, as you are finding the hard way.

Comment: well i don't know if this helps but the technician did receive the emailed text once but after that nothing...crickets..its very odd @manassehkatz could it be that the phone thinks its spam?

Comment: @twinaholic - Not the phone, the service provider for the phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look's like you defined $email but didn't use it.

```html
<?php

if ($number !=10) {
    die("You are not a human! or your answer was incorrect!, Please go back and try again.");
}
else {
mail ($email1, $confirmation_subject,$msg, 'From: ' .$confirmation_sender );
mail ($email, $confirmation_subject,$msg, );
}

if(!filter_var($email1, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    die("Invalid email ($email1)");
}
if ($email1 == $email2) {
    mail ($email, $subject, $message, "from:".$from);
    header("location: siteethankyou.php");
}
else {
    echo "This ($email2) email address is different from ($email1).\n";
}

?>
```